# Can we use & in a project name in Android Studio

Tags: android

I made a project named "App37_Gallery&_ScrollView"  in Android Studio, although the IDE didn't raise any error, I am unable to *RUN* it i.e. the won't install on the emulator and IDE says to try to uninstall and then re-install the app.

Could this problem occurred because of that '&' in Project name(Root folder's name not app_name)?

Comment: Did you tried on another emulator?

Comment: The IDE might not raise errors, but the linter will

Comment: @Rasi Yes, I did try to run it on my phone, but same problem

Comment: @cricket_007 How is my ques similar to that other one? He asking about using & in xml file while my ques is about the **Project Name** the we give while creating any new one in Android Studio ( and apparently is the name of _ROOT_ folder of that project).

Comment: @cricket_007 Hope you remove the **Duplicate** tag from the ques

Comment: Your `app_name` string is the Project name by default, so I assumed that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Ampersand is not allowed in project names. Use `\u0026` (Unicode definition) or `&amp;` if you really need it:

```
<string name = "app_name>App37_Gallery&amp;ScrollView</string>
```

Comment: Although `&amp;` also has `&` in it :)

Comment: _&amp;_ was already written in strings.xml (maybe the IDE added it automatically), but the app is still not running.